# Use pandas to calculate binned average with decimal increments

Tags: python, pandas, bin

I have a pandas dataframe for which I want to calculate the binned average. 
To bin my data, instead of using the number of bins, I'm looking for a solution (possibly an on-liner) for which I would be able to specify the bin size. For, example from this data:

```
                A     B
               0.1   4.2
               0.15  2.0
               0.17  3.0 
               0.2   6.4
               0.3   1.0
               0.35  5.0
               0.4   10.0
               0.43  2.0
               0.5   8.0
```

I want to specify `bin_size=0.1` for column A get the following dataframe as my binned average:

```
                   A       B                          
    (0.1,0.2)     0.14     3.06
    (0.3,0.4)     0.35     5.33
    (0.4,0.5)     0.44     6.66
```

If I was to specify the number of bins, I would solve it by:

```
    groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.A, bins))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(groups.mean())
```

But, as I said, I'm looking for a solution in which I specify size of the bin. Perhaps it's important to highlight that my data set has 33961 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `bins` using a numpy array equally separated by 0.1

```
ranges = np.arange(df.A.min() - 0.1, df.A.max() + 0.1, 0.1)  #[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...] 
groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.A, ranges))
groups.mean()


#               A           B
#  A        
# (0.0, 0.1]    0.100000    4.2
# (0.1, 0.2]    0.173333    3.8
# (0.2, 0.3]    0.300000    1.0
# (0.3, 0.4]    0.375000    7.5
# (0.4, 0.5]    0.465000    5.0
```